# Main difference between session and user scope custom dimension in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am understanding the use of user and session scope custom dimension. But still not getting the main difference between them.
Both are maintaining the values of dimensions in their sessions.Then what's the major difference between them. Any clear example for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you've understood, session scoped custom dimensions persists throughout the session. But user-scoped custom dimensions persists with the user. A user can have multiple sessions and the user-scoped custom dimension will be set for those sessions as well without purposely setting them with code. It will only be gone if the GA cookie is erased or something overwrites it.

Comment: Thanks!!!! It was helpful.
What you are saying is that even if the user session expires and new session is generated then the CD value will be persisted in new session?

Comment: Yup, the only caveat is that if the user clears or doesn’t store cookies. Since GA tracks them using an unique id from the cookie.